# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'order_by'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was trying to combine two `queryset` objects by `itertools chain` python predefine function and filter this with `order_by`. but i'm getting an `AttributeError`: `'list' object has no attribute 'order_by'`.
If anybody could figure out where i'm doing thing wrong then would be much appreciated. thank you so much in advance.

views.py :

```
try:
    qs = Conversation.objects.filter(
        Q(chat__from_user=user) &
        Q(chat__to_user=to_user))

    qs_2 = Conversation.objects.filter(
        Q(chat__from_user=to_user) &
        Q(chat__to_user=user))
except:
    raise ValidationError({"message":"bad request"})

all_qs = list(chain(qs, qs_2)).order_by('-created_on')
```

Comment: did you read error text? also you can merge filtering conditions into one query with or

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not `.order_by(…)` a list. But you actually do not need this anyway. You can simply "merge" the two querysets, and work with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

all_qs = Conversation.objects.filter(
        Q(chat__from_user=user, chat__to_user=to_user) |
        Q(chat__from_user=to_user, chat__to_user=user)
).order_by('-created_on')
```

As a rule of thumb, it is better to avoid lists as much as possible, since even if you manage to sort these at the Django/Python level, it is often less efficient than on the database level, which is a system that is designed to do these things efficiently.

Comment: What do you mean by doing it on a database level? Isn't this filter forwarding that to the database? If not where would you do that?

Comment: @BenjaminK: it is. The comment is about avoiding to call `list(...)` on a queryset and not work with `filter(..)`, `sorted(..)`, since then it is done at the Django/Python level and not on the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should they be sorted then? (What file (still `views.py`), What method?)

Comment: @BenjaminK: at the database, so with the `.order_by('-created_on')`, since will be put in the SQL query.

Comment: Amazing thank you for further outlining your answer. Now I get it :) so everything in my code is right, as I use `order_by` already and this will sort on the database level. Greatfull for solving this.