# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'order_by' Python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was trying to combine two `queryset objects` data by `itertools chain` python predefine function and sorting this with `order_by`. but i'm getting an `AttributeError`: `'list' object has no attribute 'order_by'`.
If anybody could figure out where i'm doing thing wrong then would be much appreciated. thank you so much in advance.

```
try:
    qs = ChatMessage.objects.filter(
            Q(from_user=user, to_user=to_user) |
            Q(from_user=to_user, to_user=user)
        )
except:
    raise ValidationError({"message":"bad request"})

data = UserChatMessageSerializer(qs, many=True, context={'request': request}).data
# qs.update(read_status=True)
for record in data:
    data1 = record['conversation']
    data2 = record['files']
    print(data2)
    from itertools import chain 
    all_results = list(chain(data1,data2)).order_by('-created_on')
```

output:

```
"all_results": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "message": "sad",
            "created_on": "2021-01-08T19:43:12.232310Z",
            "read_status": false,
            "is_edited": false,
            "chat": 8
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "message": "sad",
            "created_on": "2021-01-09T06:32:30.381712Z",
            "read_status": false,
            "is_edited": false,
            "chat": 8
        },
]
```

Comment: The reason you're getting the exception is because you're calling `order_by()` on a `list` object, not a `QuerySet` object.

Comment: with `list(chain(data1, data2))` you are making a list and a list indeed has no `order_by`.

Comment: But it is not clear to me *what* you aim to achieve. It looks quite odd that you `.order_by` in a loop and that his `all_results`, since each iteration you work with a different "record". Is it possible to share relevant models, views, serializers, and explain *what* you aim to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a `AttributeError` because a list in Python does not have a `order_by` method (as the error states). Perhaps you meant to use the `sort` method?

I'm not sure what the data you're using looks like, but here is a simple example of ordering a list with the sort method and a lambda. Hopefully you should be able to adapt it for you own code:"

```py
demo = [
    {"created_on": "2","another thing":40},
    {"created_on": "5","another thing":30},
    {"created_on": "1","another thing":60},
    {"created_on": "8","another thing":10}
]
demo.sort(key=lambda x: x["created_on"])
print(demo)
# [{'created_on': '1', 'another thing': 60}, {'created_on': '2', 'another thing': 40}, {'created_on': '5', 'another thing': 30}, {'created_on': '8', 'another thing': 10}]
```

Comment: It's worked but i'm getting the data as `ascending` format. but i want to get the data as `descending` format. if any helps would be much appreciated. thanks .

Comment: Adding `reverse=True` to `sort` should do the trick: `demo.sort(key=lambda x: x["created_on"], reverse=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not `.order_by(…)` a list. But you actually do not need this anyway. You can simply "merge" the two querysets like this

```
ChatMessage.objects.filter(
    Q(Queryset1) |
    Q(Queryset2)
  ).order_by('created_on')
```

or

```
try:
    qs = ChatMessage.objects.filter(
        Q(from_user=user, to_user=to_user) |
        Q(from_user=to_user, to_user=user)
    ).order_by('created_on')
except:
    raise ValidationError({"message":"bad request"})

data = UserChatMessageSerializer(qs, many=True, context={'request': 
request}).data
# qs.update(read_status=True)
for record in data:
    data1 = record['conversation']
    data2 = record['files']
    print(data2)
    from itertools import chain 
    all_results = list(chain(data1,data2))
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64985718/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-order-by)

Answer (score 0):

Chain order_by function to Queryset in following way and remove the order_by() call on list() object.

```
ChatMessage.objects.filter(
            Q(from_user=user, to_user=to_user) |
            Q(from_user=to_user, to_user=user)
        ).order_by('created_on')
```

Answer (score 0):

`order_by` is a method of `QuerySet` class/datatype, while by using `list` method the object is `list` not `QuerySet` now.
To merge two queryset you may use `union` method instead:

```py
qs1.union(qs2).order_by('created_on')
```

As long as both `data1` and `data2` are `QuerySet`, which you can check with `type()` function, you can use method above.

If you like to sort a list, then sorting with a lambda function would be possible:

```py
all_results = sorted(list(chain(d1,d2)), key=lambda item: item.created_on, reverse=True)
```

Change `reverse` to `True` or `False` to control ascending or descending order.